# Implementing the Android Application Silent Install Like the AppBrain fastWeb Installer

Tags: android

Hi Experts / Expert Hackers,

I'm trying to implement the Google Play application silent install feature (similar to appbrain fast web installer) on android.

So far I was able achieve the following :

1. Find out a method to retrieve the Google Play Auth Token (thus granting permission for my application to talk with Google Play application on the Phone).
2. Find out how to Retrieve the Android-Id of the Phone (This Id as I believe should be used when sending the appInstall request to the GPlay Servers or the Gplay/vending application on the android phone)
3. Find out the Protocol Buffer Request to be sent to the Google Play servers or the Gplay/vending application on the phone to Initiate the silent application download & install process. (this I found from [this](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2011/05/28/when-angry-birds-attack-android-edition/) artice)

I've been looking into this for about two weeks now but I still couldn't find the following :

Whether the AppBrain fast Web Installer uses the protocol buffer to invoke the Gplay (vending application) on the phone or the Gplay servers ?. If so is the above Protocol Buffer Request format correct ??.

If the Above Protocol Buffer Request format is correct then to Where in the Phone or Gplay server should I send the Protocol buffer request to to invoke the Silent Application download and installing procedure ?.

I also have a C2DM (now GCM) server and client setup around this task as well. Could anyone point me in the correct direction or give me any clues for solving this ?. Any help is much appreciated .